# How to determine an application is already launched or not in windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, api, c++11, windows-10

I am launching an windows desktop application by 
CATStartProcess (const char *comPath,
                 char *const argv[],
                 int wait, int *pid,
                 int *exitStatus); 
The arguments are passed to it.
If the application is already running I don't need to create a new instance for this. How can I check if this application is already running in background or not?

```
    int wait = 0;   
    int pid;
    int exitStatus;
    char *CommandArgs[9] = { 0 };
    CommandArgs[0] = (char*)usComposerExePath.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[1] = (char*)usOpen.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[2] = (char*)usComposerProjectDocPath.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[3] = (char*)strInfiniteTicket.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[4] = (char*)strDocName.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[5] = (char*)strSecurityContext.ConvertToChar();     
    CommandArgs[6] = (char*)usBusID.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[7] = (char*)usUserID.ConvertToChar();
    CommandArgs[8] = NULL;

    CATLibStatus startComposerBatchStatus = CATStartProcess((char*)usComposerExePath.ConvertToChar(), CommandArgs, wait, &pid, &exitStatus);
```

Comment: You could improve your question by adding (1) what you already tried, (2) what CATStartProcess should be, probably with a link to the documentation, and (3) with a real question what you are asking for.

Comment: When your application starts, it should check the process-tree for a process with the same name. If it is already started, it should kill itself

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Allowing only one instance can be done with a Windows mutex.

Comment: Make a single-instance application. Creating a named kernel object (like a mutex) and checking for its existence during startup is a common strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways, but I'll admit, neither of my two solutions are portable/standard C++, but you tagged Windows, so I'll give a Windows method.

The below code actually performs both checks. The first method is to use a named mutex. Windows has a "Global" mutex, which checks for running processes by any user. If the mutex already exists, then its running. If it doesn't exist, then it's not running. There's some states where things can't be easily determined, so it checks the running process list. This part is less accurate, since different permissions affects the list.

The part with mutexes will only work if you can modify the application you are trying to launch so that it creates a mutex.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include <psapi.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <advpub.h>

enum class ProcessRunningState {
    YES,
    NO,
    ERR
};

ProcessRunningState CheckIfProcessIsAlreadyRunning( DWORD currentProcessId, const wchar_t *programName, const wchar_t *programGUID, HANDLE *mutex_handle ) noexcept {

    { // Check the mutexes first
        wchar_t global_prog_name[1024] = L"Global\\";
        wcsncat_s( global_prog_name, programName, wcslen( programGUID ) );


        if ( mutex_handle ) {
            *mutex_handle = CreateMutex( NULL, TRUE, global_prog_name );
            if ( !( *mutex_handle ) ) {
                const DWORD dw = GetLastError();
                if ( dw == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
                    return ProcessRunningState::YES;
            } else {
                return ProcessRunningState::NO;
            }
        } else {
            HANDLE h = OpenMutex( SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, global_prog_name );
            if ( h ) {
                CloseHandle( h );
                return ProcessRunningState::YES;
            } else if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ) {
                return ProcessRunningState::NO;
            }
        }
    }

    { // At this point, the state is unknown, so try running through the process list
        DWORD aProcesses[2048], cProcesses;

        if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof( aProcesses ), &cProcesses ) ) {
            return ProcessRunningState::ERR;
        }

        // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

        cProcesses = cProcesses / sizeof( DWORD );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ ) {
            if ( aProcesses[i] != 0 && aProcesses[i] != currentProcessId ) {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, aProcesses[i] );

                WCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

                if ( hProcess ) {
                    HMODULE hMod;
                    DWORD cbNeeded;

                    if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof( hMod ), &cbNeeded ) ) {
                        GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, sizeof( szProcessName ) / sizeof( TCHAR ) ); // Can't error here, since this function "errors" on access
                    }/* else {
                        return ProcessRunningState::ERR;
                    }*/

                    CloseHandle( hProcess );
                }

                if ( _wcsicmp( szProcessName, programName ) == 0 ) {
                    return ProcessRunningState::YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ProcessRunningState::NO;
}
```

Calling it like so will create the mutex if possible, and basically says that "I want to run, can I?"

```
HANDLE mutex_handle;
const ProcessRunningState cur_state = CheckIfProcessIsAlreadyRunning( GetCurrentProcessId(), L"PROGRAM_NAME", programGUID, &mutex_handle );

switch ( cur_state ) {
case ProcessRunningState::ERR:
case ProcessRunningState::YES:
    return ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
default:
    break;
}
```

Calling it like so, simply checks if its already running, and launches the application if not.

```
if ( CheckIfProcessIsAlreadyRunning( GetCurrentProcessId(), L"PROGRAM_NAME", programGUID, nullptr ) == ProcessRunningState::NO ) {
    std::wstring programInstallLocation = L"path";
    std::wstring programName = programInstallLocation + L"\\PROGRAM_NAME";
    ShellExecute( NULL, L"open", programName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW );
}
```

And somewhere in your code, you would specify what `programGUID` is. For example:

```
WCHAR programGUID[] = L"ba2e95a0-9168-4b6e-bcd6-57309748df21";
```

Comment: 2020 is the wrong year to write code that uses the ANSI API. Also, if you are creating a named mutex in the global object space make sure the name is unique. The string representation of a GUID works just fine.

Comment: @IInspectable, it's old code I have laying around. It can be easily modified for both your recommendations, but yes, I do agree to both.

Comment: There's an edit button right under your answer so you can *"easily modify"* it to make it less *"odd"*. Stack Overflow used to be about quality at some point.

Comment: @IInspectable, edited now. Didn't try it, but should still work.

Comment: Actually I made the application which is being called from CATStartProcess as a single instance application. This solved my problem.